# How do I overcome this TypeError()?

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting a "TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp'" error in my code. The code that is causing the error is:

How can I fix this error?

Here is my full code

```py
models = []
models.append(('LR',LogisticRegression()))
models.append(('LDA',LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()))
models.append(('KNN',KNeighborsClassifier()))
models.append(('CART',DecisionTreeClassifier()))
models.append(('NB', GaussianNB()))
models.append(('SVM', SVC()))
# evaluate each model in turn
results = []
names = []
for name, model in models:
    kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed, shuffle=True)
    cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X_train, Y_train, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    msg = "%s: %f (%f)" % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std())
    print(msg)
```

Comment: Please post code that reproduces the issue. Your post is incomplete

Comment: Providing the error stack might help. You aren't giving any clue as to where the exception is being triggered, and that is not "full code". Also you should indicate which line is referenced in the stack.

Comment: Use f-format string `msg = f"{name}: {cv_results.mean()} {cv_results.std()}"`

Comment: @toyotaSupra It's not obvious that that would fix the problem, and if it did, it would likely just hide the *underlying* problem by converting an unintended value to a `str`.